# Yishmael - if he did Teshuva why does he continue to be punished

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, repentance-teshuvah, yishmael

We know that Yishmael early on acted in an improper manner (see for example [Bereishis Rabbah 53:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.53.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) and was resultantly banished from Avraham's household - [Bereishis 21:9-10](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.21.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

However, we learn later on ([Bereishis 25:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that following Avraham's death, Yishmael returned to bury his father along with Yitzchak. Rashi [there](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.9?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) qualifies this to mean:

> **יצחק וישמעאל.** מִכָּאן שֶׁעָשָׂה יִשְׁמָעֵאל תְּשׁוּבָה וְהוֹלִיךְ אֶת יִצְחָק לְפָנָיו, וְהִיא שֵׂיבָה טוֹבָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר בְּאַבְרָהָם (בראשית רבה):
>
> ***ISAAC AND ISHMAEL** — From this we gather that Ishmael repented of his evil ways (cf. [Bava Basra 16b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.16b.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) and yielded the precedence to Isaac. This is what is meant by the “good old age” mentioned in connection with Abraham ([Bereishis Rabbah 38:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.38.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).*

With this in mind, how then do we understand the pretty tough line we see in a couple of places against Yishmael:

1. [Sanhedrin 104a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.104a.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - Avraham cannot save Yishmael (from his heavenly judgement)
2. [Pesachim 119b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.119b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - In the future Hashem will make a feast for the righteous. The cup of blessing will be given to Avraham (so that he can lead bensching) but he will say, "I will not recite the blessing because Yishmael issued from me."

I appreciate Yishmael gave rise to a nation that would be an enemy of the Jews, but on an individual level why should he continue to warrant punishment if he was chozer b'teshuva?

Comment: I thought it was because by the time he did teshuvah, his kids already learned his bad behavior. It's not Yishmael the human who is being spoken of, but Yishmael the nation(s). I could look up sources and things, but it would be too much fuel for a sonei Yisrael who has access to Google. (In either case, a given individual isn't the same person as a national stereotype.)

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be  some question and differing opinions about whether he did complete  Teshuva or not . Most opinions hold that he did complete Teshuva.

However,The Tosfos Yeshanim Yoma 38B,  asks a similar question to the one being asked here; How can we use the name Yishmael if based on the Gemora Sanhedrin  mentioned in this question he was a Rasha? He answers that  since Hashem was the one to choose and make the name Yishmael it is used despite the way he turned out. He seems to be reaching the conclusion that according to that Gemara, Yismoal indeed never did complete Teshuva.

Rashi on Chumash brings down the Medrash of Yismael doing Teshuva, yet Rashi also (Megilah 17A) refers to him as a Rasha.

According to those that he remained a Rasha he must have done Teshuva for *some* things as the Midrash says. But not all.So in one sense yes he did Teshuva. But in other areas he remained a Rasha.

Comment: Are there opinions which say he did do a complete teshuvah? If so, how do they resolve the contradictory Gemaras brought by OP?

Comment: Most opinions are that he did full Teshuva. I don't know how they answer the Gemoras but my boich sevora is that (1)The Gemorah in Pesochim  is saying that Avraham did not want to bentsch because he had a son who for a TIME was a baal aveira (2)The Gemora in Sanhedrin is saying that in THEORY  had Yismoel not done Teshuva Avraham would not have been able to save him from punishment.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Akiva Eiger (Gilion hashas baba basra 16b) brings the Toras Chaim who asks on the gemara in Sanhedrin 104a that why did Yishmael need saving if he did teshuva. However the Reishonim in Yuma 38b imply that the gemara in Sanhedrin held Yishmael didn't do Teshuva. Therefore it's a machlokes whether Yishmael did teshuva or not. I've seen Rav Yehonasan Eibshitz say that the gemara in Pesachim 119b holds Yishmael didn't do Teshuva. On the haga they comment it's not neccessary to say that, but rather it's reffering to the nation of Yishmael. Since that nation came out of him, Avraham wouldn't be allowed to bless.

Regarding the drasha in Baba Basra that mentions Yitschak before Yishmael implying that Yishmael did teshuva, I've seen in the chumash Hagra that he explains the pasuk according to the one that holds Yishmael didn't do Teshuva.  He explains the pasuk mentions Yitschak first because he was the ben hagvira and Yishmael was the son of the maid. However I think you can explain differently based off the Gur Aryeh. The Gur Aryeh asks on Rashi what's the proof Yishmael did Teshuva, maybe he allowed Yitschak to go first because he was giving honor to the ben Hagvira (see there what he answers). I think that's what the Midrash Rabba is saying on this pasuk.The medrash says from here the son of the maid gave honor to the ben hagvira, implying that Yishmael didn't do teshuva.

There is some more gemaras that might need to be answered up, however I won't address them now, because they weren't mentioned in the question. Also the Bear Bisadeh tries to reconcile the gemara in Sanhedrin with Yishmael doing teshuva but I don't remember where he is. However probably he didn't see the reishonim in Yuma.

Answer (score -5):

The world works according to the laws of nature. One of these laws is that acts has consequences. Whether or not G-d forgives, the consequences do not go away. Thus he was punished. (David also repented) but that did not remove the consequences of their acts.

Comment: This is incorrect. The consequences can be removed with the proper repentance. See Rambam.

Comment: @robev And what is your understanding of natural laws? Repentance doesn’t magically absolve people of wrongs. Maimonides put it this way: teshuva is when a person corrects their misdeed. When an egg is broken, its shards cannot be reassembled. That is a law in nature. What you speak of, it is not Jewish but a Christian idea. You accept Paul’s idea. Your idea of repentance is alien to Judaism. It is not Jewish. Repentance is a practical endeavor. It's not pseudo-magical recitations. The world works according to the laws of nature. One of these laws is that acts has consequences.

Comment: Incorrect. It is a completely Jewish idea that if a person performs teshuva properly, and not the Christian lip service as you randomly brought up, Hashem not only forgives them but removes the need for punishment. The gemarra is full of such references. How do you understand [Makkos 3:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Makkot.3.15?lang=bi)? According to you repentance and lashes can't remove kares, since it's a natural consequence of certain prohibitions.

Comment: As this answer stands, you are not answering the question as asked. You are answering about the world and the laws of nature, which according to you does not change "[w]hether or not G-d forgives". The question does not seem to be asking about the physical world, but rather about the spiritual realm ("Avraham cannot save Yishmael (from his heavenly judgement)"). Unless you explain how your answer addresses the spiritual realm, then your answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @robev Repentance is not a biblical concept. It is not in the Bible. I demonstrated this and, I showed how King David was punshished for the adulterous relationship with Bat Sheva. Those who did wrong were punished after they repented (David also repented), but it was the consequences of their acts that do not go away, whether or not G-d forgives.

Comment: @robev 
"I do not believe in the G-d of theology who rewards good and punishes evil. My G-d created laws that take care of that. His universe is not ruled by wishful thinking, but by immutable laws.” — Einstein. As if you understand the laws of nature as he did?

Comment: I definitely understand Judaism more than Einstein. If repentance isn't biblical why does the Rambam think it is? Do you know more than the Rambam?

Comment: @Salmononius2 There is no such thing as the "spiritual realm." Prayers won't make G-d wipe out the wrongs you committed. G-d created the world to function according to the laws of nature. Any attempt to change the world through prayer, sacrifice, or magic, will fail and not change anything. It is actually arrogant. When you pray for G-d to forgive you are implying that G-d acted unwisely and your wiser than G-d and knows better than G-d how the world should work. The reality is, G-d knowingly created the world to functions according to the laws of nature in a way that is good for the world.

Comment: @TurkHill I recommend that you actually look at what Rambam wrote instead of deciding what you think he should say

Comment: @robev The world works according to the laws of nature. The Rambam knew this.

Comment: @Heshy The world works according to the laws of nature. The Rambam knew this.

Comment: @TurkHill I repeat: look at what he actually wrote.

Comment: @Heshy Rambam wrote for two audiences, the intellectuals and the common person. One needs the read the entire Guide to uncover his true view. What he wrote in MT was for the masses.

Comment: It is completely absurd to think that an intelligent person would write hundreds of pages of highly technical content that he didn't even believe.

Comment: @Heshy It has been a long tradition of philosophers to  do so, from Plato to Spinoza, to tell "necessary beliefs."

Comment: @Heshy don't worry TurkHill does this all the time. Whenever they write something that is contradicted by all Jewish sources, including their hero the Rambam, they write that the Rambam didn't mean it.

Comment: Wow. That's a whole new level of heresy right there, claiming that there is nothing beyond the physical world.

Comment: @Salmononius2 it is heresy and arrogant when you say that G-d acted unwisely and your wiser than G-d and knows better than G-d. So your saying your smarter than Einstein?

Comment: "I do not believe in the G-d of theology who rewards good and punishes evil. My G-d created laws that take care of that. His universe is not ruled by wishful thinking, but by immutable laws.” — Einstein. As if you understand the laws of nature as he did?

Comment: @Salmononius2 I, myself reject an anthropomorphic G-d.

"The natural laws of science have not only been worked out theoretically but have been proven also in practice. I cannot then believe in this concept of an anthropomorphic G-d who has the powers of interfering with these laws." Einstein

Comment: @Salmononius2 So you're claiming to be smarter than Einstein?

Comment: @TurkHill ok, so you reject Judaism.  Don't pretend otherwise.

Comment: @Heshy I, myself reject an anthropomorphic G-d and superstition. The world functions according to the laws of nature. A G-d who interferes with them is a breach of natural laws. It also suggests as Leibniz said: "G-d Almighty wants to wind up his watch from time to time: otherwise it would cease to move. He had not, it seems, sufficient foresight to make it a perpetual motion." On the contrary, I accept rational Judaism.